# Nagios plugin to read multiple status in text file.

Tags: python, shell, perl, nagios, check-mk

I have a text file (/tmp/status)on the client side which gets regularly updated by a cron job:

```
sdd1:OK sdd2:OK sdd3:WARNING sdd4:CRITICAL
```

I was looking for a plugin in nagios that can read this text file and display it on the nagios web interface in a single service.

As far as the status of this service concerned - Since there are multiple status in this text file like OK,WARNING and CRITICAL so how I should proceed ?

Comment: Best way how you can achieve this is write your own simple plugin in preferred language (Python, bash, Perl,...). You need simple condition in your script - if line contains critical status, then exit script with exit code 2 (= critical state in Nagios), if warning then.....    You get the point right?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Understood now.